# Odoo Shortcuts, Is there any Shortcut for Search more for many2many_tags widget?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

We all know that in form view if we click on Alt+Shift+E form view Edit mode shall be opened, Alt+Shift+S is going to Save the Form. 
Like this is there an shortcut for Search more... option of Many2one or Many2many Tags?

Answer (score 3):

In ODOO i have seen  only these key till now:

> For Simple CURD Operation :

1. Create a Record:accesskey="**Alt+Shift+C**"
2. Edit a Record :accesskey="**Alt+Shift+E**"
3. Save a Record  :accesskey="**Alt+Shift+S**"
4. Discard a Record :accesskey="**Alt+Shift+D**"

> For Iterating the records :

1. Move To Prev Records:accesskey="**Alt+Shift+O**"
2. Move To Next Records:accesskey="**Alt+Shift+P**"

> For Switching the view :

1. Switch to KanbanView="**Alt+Shift+K**"
2. Switch to FormView="**Alt+Shift+F**"
3. Switch to ListView="**Alt+Shift+L**"

There is no other sort key till date in [base.xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7682760dcad232829fbb5d4221f66a1ebb9d6c91/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml).

Hope this help you.

Comment: search  <!-- accesskeys not wanted in X2Many widgets -->